# Use replaceState to set scroll position (javascript history api)

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I've got a single page app that implements the javascript history api. If a user navigates from page 1 to page 2:

- I perform a history.replacestate() to store the scroll position in the stateObject
- After that I do a history.pushstate() with the url of page 2.

After a history.back I change the content back from page 1 to page 2 and set the scroll position to the saved scroll position.

So far this works fine...

Problem is when the user performs a history.forward after that. I don't have the scroll position in the javascript history object of page 2. Is there a way to store this before the history.back is fired?

Comment: How are you storing the scroll position?

Comment: Are you storing scroll positions in pushstate as well?

Comment: @jmargolistvt: In the first history.replacestate({scrollPos: position}, title, page1.html) i put it in the stateObject.

Comment: @Cybernetic: Not in the pushstate, because in the pushstate it should always be 0 (if you open a new page you will be at the top of the page)